# TypeError: can't cast Array to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, rake-task

I'm getting this error when trying to run a rake task using Nokogiri.

This is the code.

```
namespace :tops do
  desc "Get Tops Description"
  task get_description: :environment do
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://ceratoboutique.com/collections/tops"))

  price = Array.new 
  items = Array.new
  brands = Array.new
  sale_price = Array.new
  image = Array.new
  item_url = Array.new

  price = doc.xpath("//del").collect {|node| node.text.strip}
  items = doc.xpath("//div/a/h4").collect {|node| node.text.strip}
  brands = doc.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'vendor')]").collect {|node| node.text.strip}
  sale_price = doc.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'price')]/text()").collect {|node| node.text.strip}
  image = doc.xpath("/div/a/img/@src").collect {|node| node.text.strip}
  item_url = doc.css('div.details a').map { |link| link['href'] }.collect 

  price.each do |prices|
      Tops.create(description: price)
    end
  end
end
```

This is the full error.

> Rake aborted! TypeError: can't cast Array to string
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:76:in `type_cast'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:261:in`type_cast'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:295:in `block in exec_query'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:294:in`map'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:294:in `exec_query'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:68:in`
>   exec_insert'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:95:in
>   `insert'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in`
>   insert'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in
>   `insert'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:502:in`
>   _create_record'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:87:in
>   `_create_record'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in`
>   block in _create_record'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in
>   `run_callbacks'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in`
>   _create_record'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in
>   `_create_record'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in`
>   create_or_update'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in
>   `block in create_or_update'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in`
>   run_callbacks'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in
>   `create_or_update'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in`
>   save'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in
>   `save'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in`
>   save'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in`block in with_transaction_returning_status'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in
>   `block in transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in`
>   within_new_transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in
>   `transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in`transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in`block in save'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in`save'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in
>   `create' /Users/Kcummings/Sites/rvm_tests/lib/tasks/tops.rake:24:in`
>   block (3 levels) in '
>   /Users/Kcummings/Sites/rvm_tests/lib/tasks/tops.rake:23:in `each'
>   /Users/Kcummings/Sites/rvm_tests/lib/tasks/tops.rake:23:in`block (2
>   levels) in '
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in
>   `call'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in`
>   block in execute'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in
>   `each'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in`
>   execute'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in
>   `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in
>   `invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in`
>   invoke'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in
>   `invoke_task'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `each'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   block in top_level'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in
>   `run_with_threads'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in`
>   top_level'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in
>   `block in run'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in
>   `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in`' /usr/bin/rake:23:in `load' /usr/bin/rake:23:in`'

**Edit: TOPS TABLE SCHEMA**

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140824150641) do

      create_table "tops", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "brand"
        t.string   "description"
        t.string   "image"
        t.decimal  "price"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.string   "url"
      end
end
```

Comment: post your `tops` table schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You quite confusing have set `price` to be an array (rather than calling it `prices`) which was possibly a contributing factor in your typo below

```
price.each do |prices|
  Tops.create(description: price)
end
```

You are assigning the array you are iterating over, rather than the individual element that is being yielded.

Answer (score 8):

Seems that you have `description` field in table `tops` as 'varchar' or `string`, however you are trying to store array in it.

You need to change datatype of `description` field to `text` and then `serialize` the value before trying to store it.

Generate new migration file and run it, On your terminal:

```
rails g migration change_desc_in_my_tops
```

As you are using Rails 4, add following code in your migration file:

```
class ChangeDescInTops < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :tops, :description, :text
  end

  def down
    change_column :tops, :description, :string
  end
end
```

Now run migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Update your `tops` model as:

```
class Tops < ActiveModel::Base
  serialize :description, Array
  ...
  ...
end
```

Now try to run your rake task. Hope, it will help you.

**NOTE:** You should use singular model names. Your `Tops` model could be `Top`. It avoids confusion while using associations and it follows convention.